Update data using ASP.NET Core
Manage.cshtml view:
@model IEnumerable<WMS_Frontend.Models.UserView>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Manage User";
}

@* Include Modal component *@
<partial name="_Modal" />

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "User")'">
    Add User
</button>

<table class="display table" id="ManageUser" style="width:100%">
   //TABLES 
</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="usersModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="usersModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="usersModalLabel">User Details</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container mt-5">
                    <form id="userForm" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Update" method="post">
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-3">
                                        <input value="UserID" for="modalUserID" type="hidden" id="modalUserID" class="form-control" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                   
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                        <label for="modalFirstName">First Name:</label>
                                        <input for="FirstName" type="text" id="modalFirstName" class="form-control" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                        <label for="modalMiddleName">Middle Name:</label>
                                        <input for="MiddleName" type="text" id="modalMiddleName" class="form-control" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                        <label for="modalLastName">Last Name:</label>
                                        <input for="LastName" type="text" id="modalLastName" class="form-control" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label for="modalEmail">Email:</label>
                                    <input for="Email" type="text" id="modalEmail" class="form-control" readonly>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label for="modalPassword">Password :</label>
                                    <input for="Password" type="password" id="modalPassword" class="form-control" readonly>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                        <label for="modalStatus">Status:</label>
                                        <select  id="modalStatus" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="1">Unlocked</option>
                                            <option value="2">Locked</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Contacts -->

                        <h5>Contacts</h5>
                        <div id="modalContacts"></div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="modifyCheckbox">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="modifyCheckbox">
                                Modify Information
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitButton" disabled>Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var successMessage = '@TempData["SuccessMessage"]';
            var errorMessage = '@TempData["ErrorMessage"]';
            if (successMessage) {
                var successModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('successModal'));
                successModal.show();
            }
            if (errorMessage) {
                var errorModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('failModal'));
                errorModal.show();
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var form = document.getElementById('userForm');
            var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
            var originalFormValues = {}; // Object to store original form values

            // Function to check if form values have changed
            function formValuesChanged() {
                var formInputs = form.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="checkbox"]), select');
                for (var i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
                    var input = formInputs[i];
                    var inputId = input.id;
                    var inputValue = input.value;
                    if (originalFormValues[inputId] !== inputValue) {
                        return true; // Form value changed
                    }
                }
                return false; // No changes detected
            }

            // Function to update originalFormValues with current form values
            function updateOriginalFormValues() {
                var formInputs = form.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="checkbox"]), select');
                for (var i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
                    var input = formInputs[i];
                    var inputId = input.id;
                    var inputValue = input.value;
                    originalFormValues[inputId] = inputValue;
                }
            }

            // Update originalFormValues on page load
            updateOriginalFormValues();

            // Event listener for form inputs (excluding checkboxes)
            form.addEventListener('input', function () {
                if (formValuesChanged()) {
                    submitButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
                } else {
                    submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });

            // Event listener for checkbox to toggle form inputs readonly status
            var modifyCheckbox = document.getElementById('modifyCheckbox');
            modifyCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
                var isReadOnly = !modifyCheckbox.checked;
                var formInputs = form.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="checkbox"]), select');
                formInputs.forEach(function (input) {
                    // Disable age field explicitly
                    if (input.id !== 'modalAge') {
                        input.readOnly = isReadOnly;
                    }
                });

                // Update originalFormValues when modifying is checked
                if (!isReadOnly) {
                    updateOriginalFormValues();
                }

                // Check if submit button should be enabled
                if (formValuesChanged()) {
                    submitButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
                } else {
                    submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });
        });

       
        </script>
        }

UserController:
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(UserView updateUser)
{
    var user = await _context.WMS_User
           .Include(u => u.UserDetails)
           .Include(u => u.Contacts)
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserID == updateUser.UserID);

    user.Status = updateUser.Status;
    user.UserDetails.FirstName = updateUser.FirstName; // Assuming FirstName is editable
    user.UserDetails.MiddleName = updateUser.MiddleName;
    user.UserDetails.LastName = updateUser.LastName;
    user.UserDetails.Email = updateUser.Email;

    user.ModifiedBy = "SYSTEM";
    user.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

    user.UserDetails.FirstName = updateUser.FirstName;
    user.UserDetails.MiddleName = updateUser.MiddleName;
    user.UserDetails.LastName = updateUser.LastName;
    user.UserDetails.Email = updateUser.Email;

    user.UserDetails.ModifiedBy = "SYSTEM";
    user.UserDetails.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

    // Handle new contacts
    foreach (var newContact in updateUser.Contacts)
    {
        var contact = new UserContact
            {
                UserID = user.UserID,
                ContactType = newContact.ContactType,
                ContactNumber = newContact.ContactNumber,
                ModifiedBy = "SYSTEM",
                ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
            };
        user.Contacts.Add(contact);
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("Manage", "User");
}



Can someone help me? I am encountering a problem during the update of the data using ASP.NET Core. I trying to update user details, then after I submit the form, the value of the modal was null.
Before on this, I have tables and that tables display all the users in each user has view button now when the user clicks the view button it display the related details on that user now if the user wants to modify the information just click the checkbox modify the input readonly becomes false. I trying to update the lastname but the problem null value.

It sounds like an issue with model binding. Have you checked whether the expected content is included in the POST request?

move the CreateEdit form into a partial view and simply put this partial view into the modal. in this partial view, set the model to be "UserView" (and not an IEnumerable). also try removing the "id" attributes from the form elements because asp-for attributes should be enough.

also in Update action, you should check if provided data is valid before performing any actions.

I answered your another question,so I know you use id to bind the data using javascript.So you can remove the attribute for  add attribute "name" ="UserDetails.FirstName" if it in the UserDetail table  add attribute "name" ="FirstName" if it in the User table add so on. this can solve your problem but it will change a lot.
This attribute "asp-for"  extracts the name of the specified model property into the rendered HTML .Use it you shouldn't bind the data using javascript.I write an example  using  "asp-for"   for you. I hope this can help you.
1). controller.cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
 
    var user = await _context.Users.Include(d => d.Contacts).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id); 
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(user);
}
      
// POST: Users/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
// For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id,  User user)
{
    if (id != user.Id)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var _user = await _context.Users.Include(m => m.Contacts).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<User>(_user,"", c => c.FirstName, c => c.LastName, c => c.Contacts))
            {
                try
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
                {
                    //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                        "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                        "see your system administrator.");
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
                    
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!UserExists(user.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
       /* return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));*/
    }
    return View(user);
}

2).  Edit. cshtml
<form asp-action="Edit" >
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Contacts.ContactType" class="control-label" ></label>
        <input  asp-for="Contacts.ContactType"  class="form-control"  />
    <span asp-validation-for="Contacts.ContactType" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
 

3). The results are:



